# Html-Overlay cross domain issues with Minko Framework

Tags: javascript, c++, webserver, minko

Development is on Windows, just trying to run THREE.js on html-overlay in Minko, a C++ framework.

My files need to load textures and materials which Chrome and other major browsers block because CORS policy. Outside of the Minko development environment, the files work fine on a normal hosted environment.

The [docs](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/doc/tutorial/Targeting_HTML5.md) lead me to believe if I just host the files normally outside of the compiled Minko application, there would be no issue. (And build_html5.bat doesn't exist)

Here is a debug image:

[image: showing the errors 'null' from not being able to obtain the texture/model files]

Running the same files without a webserver in chrome with devtools report *similar errors as the image above.*

Comment: What has `c++` to do with this?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o, the framework is a c++ framework, if any changes are needed to be made to the modules etc to host my files, then it would encompass c++.

Comment: So you're asking to debug this c++ framework?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o No, I'm asking if there are any workarounds to getting my files up in a server environment. The docs were quite brief on that matter. Its a very specific question, I know, but wouldn't anyone to install it just to reproduce it, it took a very long time just to configure it :D. I was just hoping if anyone had experience with it.

Comment: Sorry, what you're asking is not clear at all.

Comment: Set the image and URL link